# MUP Deploy : MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb mongodb:27017]

Tags: mongodb, docker, meteor, mup

I am facing below issue while mup deploy.

```
[18.220.xxx.xxx] x Verifying Deployment: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    meteor app on port:80

    /built_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
                                                    throw(ex);
                                                    ^
    MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb mongodb:27017]
        at Pool.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
        at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
        at Pool.emit (events.js:210:7)
        at Connection.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:318:30)
        at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
        at Connection.emit (events.js:213:7)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:187:49)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
        at emitOne (events.js:115:13)

    => Redeploying previous version of the app

    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

    To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=100'

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And also when I am trying to list all containers mongo is not taking any port. What to do?

```
sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                  NAMES
789025a88f4a        mongo:3.4.1               "/entrypoint.sh mo..."   28 minutes ago      Restarting (100) 11 minutes ago                          mongodb
739b9606ab63        mup-rightnxtprod:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'bash ..."   24 hours ago        Restarting (1) 11 minutes ago     0.0.0.0:3003->80/tcp   rightnxtProd
f4201c547e37        mup-rightnxttest:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'bash ..."   2 days ago          Restarting (1) 11 minutes ago     0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp   rightnxttest
```

Result of docker run is:

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongo
Error response from daemon: Container 789025a88f4a506112fc16c13aa33b71922c267bdfe650bc667109d5fdae076e is not running
```

mup.js env variable

```
env: {      
      ROOT_URL: 'http://example.com',      
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/example',      
      PORT: 3003,   
 },
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: mongodb container is dead, can you re-check mongodb container ?

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply. How to check that?

Comment: That first error states that it cannot resolve name "mongodb" to IP address. Missing `/etc/hosts` (or DNS) entry?

Comment: in etc hosts file is there whose contains are  : 127.0.0.1 localhost
The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

Comment: container mongodb is dead , check logs it  : docker logs 789025a88f4a

Comment: once mongodb container started, change :      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://172.17.42.1:27017/example', (explain : 172.17.42.1 is ip address gateway of network for container.

Comment: docker logs result:  Insufficient free space for journal files
Please make at least 3379MB available in /data/db/journal or use --smallfiles exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
: going to flush diaglog...
shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
shutdown: final commit...
shutdown: closing all files...
closeAllFiles() finished
now exiting
shutting down with code:100

Comment: out of space, remove some no-need files, then start mongodb container again

Comment: It may sound dumb but can you please tell me which files to remove as I  am unable to redirect to /data

Comment: can you print the output `df -h` here

Comment: Result : df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M   41M  355M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       15G   12G  2.5G  83% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000

Comment: at least 3379MB for /

Comment: What I understand is root must have 3379 MB, is it right?

Comment: yes, it's right

Comment: Thank you. Now I am working on allocating more space to root. I will let you know once it is done.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Thank you so much. Issue was related to storage size only and it is solved with your help.